# Why when I use Image control in Winforms to convert an image from jpg -> png it gets cropped

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap

In c#, I use Image to convert image  from jpg -> png it will cropped. Even I set resolution, still the same

Here is the code:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
image.Save("Image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
image.Dispose();
```

The result (I use android studio icon as example):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKfYE.png)

I use Image to convert image  from jpg -> png it will cropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Bitmap` namespace

```C#
    static void ConvertJpgToPng(string imagePath)
    {
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath))
        {
            // Create a new Bitmap with the same dimensions as the original image
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);

            // Create a Graphics object from the Bitmap
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                // Draw the original image onto the new Bitmap
                g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
            }

            // Save the new Bitmap as PNG
            bitmap.Save("Image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed a little bit (without using void) to make it more easier